# How can I pass the result from a python decorator to my class?

Tags: python, python-decorators

I use tornado and a jwt decorator as below:

```
def jwtauth(handler_class):
    """
        Tornado JWT Auth Decorator
    """
    def wrap_execute(handler_execute):
        def require_auth(handler, kwargs):

            auth = handler.request.headers.get(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER)
            if auth:
                parts = auth.split()

                if not is_valid_header(parts):
                     return_header_error(handler)

                token = parts[1]                            
                try:                   
                    result = jwt.decode(
                        token,
                        SECRET_KEY,
                        options=jwt_options
                    )                
                except Exception as err:
                    return_auth_error(handler, str(err))

            else:
                handler._transforms = []
                handler.write(MISSING_AUTHORIZATION_KEY)
                handler.finish()

            return result

        def _execute(self, transforms, *args, **kwargs):

            try:
                result = require_auth(self, kwargs)
            except Exception:
                return False

            return handler_execute(self, transforms, *args, **kwargs)

        return _execute

    handler_class._execute = wrap_execute(handler_class._execute)
    return handler_class

@jwtauth
class MyHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):    
    def post(self):
        unit = json.loads(self.request.body.decode('utf-8'))
        # TODO:
        # get the result from jwtauth decorator and use it here

        print(result) # The result from jwtauth
```

Now, I'd like to get the jwt decode result and pass into MyHandler for further verification. Can I do it? I checked most of the comment that I can pass the parameter to a decorator but I cannot get from it. Is is possible to pass the jwtauth result to my function?

Comment: Can't you just give it to the MyHandler instance as an attribute by doing `handler.jwt_decode_result = result`?

Comment: your snippet code seems like to be a monkey-patch, add more function to MyHandler._execute  which seems to add token verification. Could you add more specific information? I suppose this is a true/pass result for this kinds of function

Comment: @JamesMchugh Thanks for your tips! I get the result by adding handler.jwt_decode_result = result.

Comment: I must agree with @hanleilei though, this does seem like a but of a monkey-patch. What were you trying to accomplish with this? It seems like it might be an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: There is an owner information in the JWT token that I would like to use it in MyHandler. But the JWT token already decoded by the decorator and I would like to re-use the result instead of decode it again. The  `handler.jwt_decode_result = result` pass the jwt decoded result to MyHandler. After I add this line and print out the result message in MyHandler, I could get decoded result. That is exactly what I want. Thank you for your help. How can I mark this question as answered?

Answer (score 0):

A class decorator takes your class and spits out a new version of your class (usually with some features added to it). In this case, the `@jwtauth` decorator takes your class and spits out a new class that makes sure that each request is checked for a valid JWT token in the authorization header. [`tornado.web.RequestHandler._execute` internally calls `post`](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/stable/tornado/web.py#L1697). The current behavior is that if the JWT token auth fails, then `post` will never be called.

In short, you probably want to just raise an error below instead of returning False.

```
        try:
            result = require_auth(self, kwargs)
        except Exception:
            return False
```

If you need to add more logic about what kind of error to raise, then you probably want to pass that into the decorator along with the class.